# Appending (insert into) pivot results into an existing SQL table

Tags: sql, t-sql, pivot, insert-into

I have a stored proc that creates a table using the pivot function (let's call it table A). In order to keep things tidy I have created another procedure where I would like the pivot results to insert into table A, however the insert into function doesn't appear to work in combination with the pivot function does anyone have any ideas of how to work around this?

Also, both procedures work fine other than the insert into element of the second one.

The pivot element of the script is as follows:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.A
CAST([ColumnA] AS VARCHAR(500))
,ColumnB
,ColumnC
,ColumnD
,ColumnE
,Apr = IsNull([1],0)
,May = IsNull([2],0)
,Jun = IsNull([3],0)
,Jul = IsNull([4],0)
,Aug = IsNull([5],0)
,Sep = IsNull([6],0)
,Oct = IsNull([7],0)
,Nov = IsNull([8],0)
,[Dec] = IsNull([9],0)
,Jan = IsNull([10],0)
,Feb = IsNull([11],0)
,Mar = IsNull([12],0)
,YTD = IsNull([13],0)
From xx_CTE
PIVOT (
   Sum(value)
   For month in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],
            [8],[9],[10],[11],[12],[13])
) AS Summary
```

For the above I'm getting...

> (39318 row(s) affected)
>
> (2883 row(s) affected)
>
> (3616 row(s) affected) Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Procedure
>   usp_sproc1, Line 109 String or binary data would be truncated. The
>   statement has been terminated.
>
> (1 row(s) affected)

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Jamie

Comment: Please post all of the code, including the CTE defintion.

Comment: your insert statement is failing because something from columns A-E won't fit in your table, the value(s) are too long.  You need to increase the size of your text columns in your table or just insert the leftmost characters of those columns up to the column definition length.  The pivot is just confusing you.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1.**

The first column in you target table is shorter than 500.
Truncate the column data to the proper size or increase the target column size.

**Option 2.**

You have `triggers` on the target table that cause the issue.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the comments. I've figured it out now, the field size of one of the columns in the target table was varchar (8) and I was trying to insert 9 characters! I'll get there eventually.

Cheers
Jamie